# Application of "Every nonzero residue modulo a prime can be represented as a power of a primitive root."

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I am reading a machine learning [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.02177.pdf), and this paragraph below doesn't quite make sense. How is x+y (mod p−1) and x*y (mod p) equivalent? Suppose p = 5 and x = 3 and y = 4, then clearly 7 mod 4 =3 isn't equal to 12 mod 5 = 2. I'm also not sure how the line "every nonzero residue modulo a prime can be represented as a power of a primitive root." relates to this fact.

> Since the operands are presented to the neural network as unrelated
> abstract symbols, the operations x+y (mod p−1) and x*y (mod p) with a
> prime number p and non-zero x, y are indistinguishable from the neural
> network’s perspective (and similarly x − y (mod p − 1) and x/y (mod
> p)). This is because every nonzero residue modulo a prime can be
> represented as a power of a primitive root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with your example with $p=5$, observe that $2$ is a primitive root. That means its powers yield all the nonzero congruence classes:
$$
2^0 \equiv 2^4 \equiv 1,\  2^1 \equiv 2,\  2^2 \equiv 4,\  2^3 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}.
$$
Since $2^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ the exponents work modulo $4$.
$$
$$
So to multiply modulo $5$ we add exponents modulo $5-1 = 4$:
$$
3 \times 4 \equiv 2^3 \times 2^2 = 2^5 \equiv 2^1 = 2 \pmod{5}.
$$

Comment: Really nice use of a simple but non-trivial example to demonstrate a point. My answer was a hurried comment, upgraded because it was really an answer. This does the job.

Answer (score 1):

They are related not by identity but by isomorphism. A primitive root enables you to do multiplying by adding exponents (discrete logarithm), which is doing arithmetic modulo $p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a primitive root mod $p$ is that it generates the multiplicative group,  which is thus cyclic.

As we know there's two notations available for any cyclic group,  both additive and multiplicative.   The correspondence is $x^n\leftrightarrow nx$.

But there's more.   On one hand we have the additive group $\Bbb Z_{p-1}.$  On the other the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_p^×.$ (That there *is* a primitive modulo $p$ is not trivial.  That accounts for the ability to switch modulus,  between $p$ and $p-1,$ in the passage. This is a topic in number theory. )